Why is cheating in marriage called "绿帽子“ (green hat) in Chinese language?
Three years ago on the St. Patrick's Day, I was talking with my friend Jack who was from China about interesting things about St. Patrick's Day, and when I mentioned to him the green hats that people wear, his expression became very weird, and he said that in Chinese language "green hat" means cheating in marriage and no one will wear it. I was quite amazed by it, and I am very curious about how "绿帽子" (green hat) was given this strange meaning. Can somebody help me explain it? Thanks!

I think this is a dupe. Check here: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/29242/4136

This question is similar to: 戴绿帽子 as based on a pun?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


在中国人的语境当中，绿帽子一词有羞辱含义。
In Chinese minds, the phrase green hat indicates humiliation.

官家的妓院，隶属礼部教坊司。
Official brothels, subordinate to the Public Instruction Department of the Ministry of Confucian Rites
角冠: 道冠。a hat for wearing in the street.
绿帽子
在中国人的语境当中，绿帽子一词有羞辱含义。
In Chinese minds, the phrase green hat indicates humiliation.
绿色在中国古代被视为低贱者的用色，
In Ancient China, green was regarded as a colour used by the lower castes,
《汉书·东方朔传》提到馆陶公主刘嫖的情夫董偃，
《汉书·东方朔传》mentions 馆陶 princess 刘嫖's lover 董偃，
头戴绿帻，颜师古注道，：“绿帻，贱人之服也。”
(who) wore a green turban, 颜师古 commented: "(A) green head-covering is the dress of base persons."
唐朝诗人李白在《古风》中也有“绿帻谁家子，
Tang poet 李白 in 《古风》also says "Green turban whose family,
卖珠轻薄儿”之句，
sells (their) pearls is a philanderer" this phrase,
可见当时绿色为低贱者所用的颜色。
(we) can see (at) that time green was the colour worn by the lower castes.
唐宋时期，
During the Tang and Song period,
视碧青绿诸色为贱民所穿服装之色。
(people) regarded blues and greens as colours worn by lowly people.
《闻见录》中，
In 《闻见录》,
唐代地方官吏对犯罪之人“不加杖罚，但令裹碧头巾以辱之”。
(in the) Tang period regional officials vis-à-vis criminals (would)
“不加杖罚，但令裹碧头巾以辱之”。
"Not punish by flogging, but order them to wear a blue-green head cloth as symbol of their disgrace."
沈括在《梦溪笔谈》中写道：
沈括 in 《梦溪笔谈》wrote:
“苏州有不逞子弟，
"(In) 苏州 there are (people) who secretly frequent brothels,
纱帽下著青巾，
under their hat is a green cloth
孙伯纯知州判云：
孙伯(a) righteous official judged saying
’巾帽用青，屠沽何异?’
(wear) green head-cloth, (or be) put to death what is the difference?'
”这表明在唐宋人心目中,
”This makes clear that during the Tang and Song people regarded,
穿戴碧绿青诸色的是最低贱的人。
wearing any kind of blue-green or green (clothes) indicated a very lowly person.
一般认为，自元代开始，
(It is) generally believed, beginning with the Mongol dynasty,
碧绿青诸色的服装限于“娼妓”所穿。
wearing any kind of blue-green or green was the reserve of prostitutes.
《元典章》规定：“娼妓穿皂衫，戴角巾儿;娼妓家长并亲属男子，裹青头巾。”
《元典章》stipulate: "Prostitutes (should) wear black blouses, wear triangular scarves;
娼妓家长并亲属男子，裹青头巾。”
The head of the family of a prostitute and male relatives (should) wear green turbans."
明太祖朱元璋于洪武三年(1370年)下诏规定：
明太祖 AKA朱元璋 in his third year as Emperor (1370) issued an imperial edict:
“教坊司乐艺着卍字顶巾，
" Public Instruction Department pleasure women (must) wear 卍 symbol (on their) head cloth,
系灯线褡膊，
and a girdle of lamp-line,
乐妓明角冠皂褙子，
Pleasure women (must be) marked by a triangular hat of black cloth or paper
不许与民妻同。”
(they) are not allowed to (wear) the same as other women."
同时还规定：
Also stipulated:
“教坊司伶人常服绿色巾，以别士庶人服。”
"Public Instruction Department actors usually wear green turbans,
以别士庶人服。”
not the same colour as nobles and ordinary people wear
到了明朝朱元璋明令让娼妓家的男子必须头戴绿巾，
In the reign of Ming Dynasty 朱元璋 male members of prostitutes families were ordered to wear green turbans,
腰系红褡膊，
red waistbands,
足穿带毛猪皮鞋，
(on their) feet (must) wear wool or pigskin shoes,
不许在街道中间行走，
(they are) not allowed to walk in the middle of the street,
只准在左右两边“靠边走”。
(they are) only allowed to walk on the left- or the right-side (of the street).
由此一来，
From this,
人们见着戴“绿帽子”的便知其家中那位是“青楼一族”，
(we can see) People regarded those who wear green headwear belong to families who are involved in brothels,
戴“绿帽子”也成为某男子的妻女卖淫或妻子私下“偷汉子”的俗称。
wearing "green headwear" also became a term to refer to some people's wives who either engaged in prostitution, or women who "stole others husbands".
另据明朝郎瑛所撰的笔记《七修类稿》载，
Also according to Ming Dynasty's 郎瑛 records 《七修类稿》
相传于春秋时期，
tradition in the Spring and Autumn Period,
依靠妻女卖淫收入为生的男子以绿头巾裹头作为识别。
men who relied on income from their wives' or daughters' prostitution wore a green head-cloth as a distinguishing symbol.
Personally, I find there is some confusion about where green stops and blue begins. Chinese friends often say things like "that green bag", pointing to a blue bag!

在現下,＂绿帽子＂的含义就是指女子背着自己的老公偷汉子(woman has out of marriage affair - adultery)。
早在唐代，绿色就代表卑贱的意思，例如娼夫一词，就是男人让自己的女人出去做皮肉生意，而自己戴一个绿帽子出去招揽生意。
到了明朝朱元璋明令让娼妓家(青楼 - Brothel)的男子必须头戴绿巾，腰系红褡膊，足穿带毛猪皮鞋。 由此一来，人们见着戴“绿帽子”的便知其家中那位是“青楼一族”，“戴绿帽子”也成为某男子的妻女卖淫或妻子私下“偷汉子”的俗称。
